# Ionic 2 karma test failed 'ion-label' is not a known element

Tags: angular, unit-testing, ionic-framework, ionic2, karma-jasmine

On running npm test i am getting this error on my component ->

```
  **Can't bind to 'formGroup' since it isn't a known property of 
   'form'. 
   ("
  </div>
<form [ERROR ->][formGroup]="loginForm" text-center>
<ion-list>
"): ng:///DynamicTestModule/Login.html@18:6
'ion-label' is not a known element:
1. If 'ion-label' is an Angular component, then verify that it is part 
of this module.
2. If 'ion-label' is a Web Component then add 'CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA' 
to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component to suppress this message. 
 ("
<ion-item>
    [ERROR ->]<ion-label floating>Email</ion-label>
    <ion-input type="email" formControlName="email" [class.inva"): 
 ng:///DynamicTestModule/Login.html@25:4
'ion-input' is not a known element:
1. If 'ion-input' is an Angular component, then verify that it is part 
of this module.
2. If 'ion-input' is a Web Component then add 'CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component to suppress this message. ("
<ion-item>
    <ion-label floating>Email</ion-label>
    [ERROR ->]<ion-input type="email" formControlName="email" [class.invalid]="!loginForm.controls.email.valid && ("): ng:///DynamicTestModule/Login.html@26:4
'ion-item' is not a known element:
```

**1. If 'ion-item' is an Angular component, then verify that it is part of this module.
2. If 'ion-item' is a Web Component then add 'CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' `enter code here`of this component to suppress this message. ("
    [ERROR ->]****

this is my test.ts

```
     import 'zone.js/dist/long-stack-trace-zone';
      import 'zone.js/dist/proxy.js';
import 'zone.js/dist/sync-test';
import 'zone.js/dist/jasmine-patch';
import 'zone.js/dist/async-test';
import 'zone.js/dist/fake-async-test';

import { FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { getTestBed, TestBed } from '@angular/core/testing';
import { BrowserDynamicTestingModule, platformBrowserDynamicTesting } from '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic/testing';
import { App, Config, Form, IonicModule, Keyboard, DomController, MenuController, NavController, Platform } from 'ionic-angular';
import { ConfigMock } from './mocks';




// Unfortunately there's no typing for the `__karma__` variable. Just 
 declare it as any.
declare var __karma__: any;
declare var require: any;

// Prevent Karma from running prematurely.
__karma__.loaded = function (): void {
  // noop
};

// First, initialize the Angular testing environment.
getTestBed().initTestEnvironment(
  BrowserDynamicTestingModule,
  platformBrowserDynamicTesting(),
);

// Then we find all the tests.
let context: any = require.context('./', true, /\.spec\.ts/);

// And load the modules.
context.keys().map(context);

// Finally, start Karma to run the tests.
__karma__.start();
``
```

Comment: Have a look at this: https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/forms.html

Answer (score 12):

Did you import IonicModule when configuring your test suite?
Something like (in test.ts):

```
public static configureIonicTestingModule(components: Array<any>): typeof TestBed {
  return TestBed.configureTestingModule({
    declarations: [
      ...components,
    ],
    providers: [
      App, Form, DomController
    ],
    imports: [
      FormsModule,
      IonicModule, // <- this here
    ],
  });
}
```

Comment: i not able to understand where should i add it this is my test.ts

Comment: @sachinkaushik your tests probably have a test entrypoint that is defined in karma.conf.ts, usually it is src/test.ts. You should add this to this test.ts defined in the karma.conf.js

Comment: i have added still facing the same problem but now i am getting this 
Error: Can't resolve all parameters for FormGroup: (?, ?, ?).

Comment: @sachinkaushik I think you add it on your .spec.ts file